# django rest framework. Как вернуть в json запись, которой нет в бд

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть такая модель данных.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()


class CourseParticipant(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', related_name='courses', on_delete=None)
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name='students', on_delete=None)
    completed = models.BooleanField()
```

Под эту модель есть вьюха:

```
class CourseView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    serializer = CourseSerializer(courses, many=True)
    return Response({"courses": serializer.data})
```

И сереализатор под эту вьюху и модель данных:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
start_date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Мне нужно возвращать в формате json такое представление.

```
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "name": "Math",
            "start_date": "2019-06-26",
            "end_date": "2019-06-26",
            "students_count": 5,
        }
    ]
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно получить "students_count".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю Вам явно связать модели, например, с помощью `ForeignKey` и использовать декоратор `property`, который позволяет обращаться к функции (методу) как к атрибуту.

***Пример:***

```py
...
class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    @property
    def students_count(self):
        return self.students.count()
```

Каждое обращение к `Course.students_count` будет возвращать Вам актуальное значение. Вы можете добавить это поле в serializer и всё будет работать.